# Let $\{X(t); t\ge 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda =2$. Find the probability $\Pr\{X(1)\le 2\}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Let $\{X(t); t\ge 0\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda =2$. Find the probability $\Pr\{X(1)\le 2\}$.

I don't know how to calculate this kind of probabilities, I just know how to calculate when it has an equal sign $=$ but not with the $\leq$ sign.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Loosely speaking, $X(t)$ counts the number of "arrivals" until time $t$. If you know how to "calculate when it has an equal sign", then notice that
$$P(X(1)\leq 2) = P\left(\bigcup_{k =0}^2 X(1) = k\right).$$

Comment: Therefore $P(X(1)\leq 2) = P\left(\bigcup_{k =0}^2 X(1) = k\right)=P(X(1)=0)+P(X(1)=2)+P(X(1)=2)$ ?

Comment: Yes. The events are disjoint.

Comment: are disjoints because of the definition of Poisson process i.e. the intervals are independent random variables, am I correct?

Comment: Is there another way to compute the above probability?

Comment: You can use arrival times instead, but it's not any easier.

Comment: I was just wondering because it won't be easier either when there is 100 instead of 2..haha

Comment: Oh, haha. I doubt they will ask you for that.

Comment: yeah you're right